If morality is real and has causal power, could science detect the moment the "moral ontology" causes a measurable effect on the physical world?
If morality is real in an objective manner, then it must exist ontologically "somewhere" and "somehow."
Moreover, this "moral ontology" must also have causal power, because in this physical world, there are beings (like us humans) who actively discuss and act upon moral principles. For morality to be real ontologically and have real effects on the physical world, it must interact with it in some measurable way. Therefore, it should be possible for science, particularly physics, to study when, where, and how this moral ontology exerts its influence on physical reality.
For example, if a human gives a speech about morality, the speech is a physical event (sound waves in the air) that could, in principle, be traced back to prior physical causes. At some point in this causal chain, if morality is indeed objective, we should encounter a point where this "moral ontology" intervenes and causes a tangible effect in physical reality.
Without such an interaction, the notion of an objective morality becomes questionable, as it would imply that morality, while real, has no measurable or observable impact on the world. This would challenge the very idea of morality as an objective force or aspect of reality that governs or guides human actions in any meaningful way.
If the reasoning above holds, wouldn't it follow that science should be able to study whether this "moral ontology" has measurable physical effects? Could physics, for instance, eventually discover a kind of "moral force" that produces measurable effects on the brain under specific conditions, perhaps even formalizable in mathematical terms?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes, but...
Chairs are real, and yet there is no "chair force" that produces measurable effects on the universe.
To choose something slightly less tangible, the federal interest rate is real, and yet there is no "federal interest rate force."
Most things that are real, are not represented as fundamental forces of the universe. Most things are instead patterns of existing stuff. Chairs do have causal effects on the universe, and the federal interest rate does, too. But these effects are nothing more than the effects of the more fundamental stuff they are made up of. The chairs are not ontologically privileged.
So it is plausible that morality could have effects on the universe, and also that morality is a pattern or arrangement of other simpler stuff, and the effects of morality are nothing more than the effects of the other simpler stuff.
What patterns could morality be made up of? Well: we can speak of morally good and bad acts. If we pick some arbitrary standard for what we call "good" and "bad," then the morally good acts and morally bad acts become definite, distinct sets. The morally good acts do have effects on the universe, and the morally bad acts also have effects on the universe, different ones. So this is how morality could have causal effects on the universe.
The real question is the arbitrariness of the standard. Must the standard be fully arbitrary, or is there some particular standard that wise-enough people might eventually agree on?
"Good" and "bad" have the nature of preferences: what we call good, we prefer, and what we call bad, we do not prefer. But often we may have a preference initially, and then later events and the power of hindsight show us that we were wrong to have that preference. What we thought good, we realize with the wisdom of hindsight, was not good.
If we take learning and hindsight to the theoretical maximum, what would we in the end call good, and what would we in the end call bad? This could be a non-arbitrary basis for moral goodness and badness.

"This could be a non-arbitrary basis for moral goodness and badness." How exactly? What if hindsight leads to one conclusion for one person and another conclusion for another person?

@user80226 It is my belief that wise-enough people would tend to agree. For Bayesian propositions, this is provable; see Aumann's agreement theorem. For moral propositions, it's less clear, but what would cause disagreement between two arbitrarily wise, rational people who share all the same information and reasoning with each other?

@causative But then you would have a problem of arbitrariness at the reasoning level. Why should they have one particular way of reasoning instead of another?

Your federal interest example only makes sense from some extreme physicalist reading of reality. The interest rate is of course an abstraction. But there is no force? Seriously? This (and such) are the forces that drive wars and millions to think it moral to kill other millions. For an eg draw a straight line from  Treaty of Versailles to WWII.

@Rushi (1) There's no fundamental force of nature specifically associated with interest rate. Of course there are forces, just as forces are involved with chairs. (2) The interest rate is embodied in a complex pattern of documents (sheets of paper), words (sound waves), and digital announcements (patterns of electrons) exchanged between the Federal Reserve, media outlets, and banks. What we call an abstraction can generally be identified with some physical basis. A "physical pattern" is a fairly abstract notion itself, and so we should not be surprised other abstractions can reduce to it.

Yeah...  as I said ... from a physicalist pov... On a physics site to cite a non physicalist pov would be to fall outside of physics. But in philosophy non physicalist views have a place. See this answer which talks of a non physics view of energy

You ask for the mechanism how  moral convictions shape our behaviour.

The question does not restrict to moral convictions, it is analogous
for religious or political convictions etc. It is the question for
the mechanism which triggers our bodily actions or omission of
action according to our convictions.
You ask for the bridge
between the moral  level and the physical level. We can experience
the will resulting from our convictions and we can observe the
behaviour. But the question is how to bridge the phenomenological
level and the neurobiological level, i.e. to naturalize our moral
convictions which are action guiding. In short:



The search for the neuronal correlate of morality.


An early investigation of such convictions is due to
Sigmund Freud. He called “superego” the sum of all cultural rules we
take over during the early education from our parents. These rules
also include basic rules of morality. These rules must be
incorporated in our memory similarly like any personal experience
which determines our behaviour. And neuronal plasticity may change them at later time.

One century ago Freud could not
support his hypotheses by results from neuroscience.
IMO action guiding convictions are coded by specific mental
processes, in specific areas of the brain, and with a specific
temporal pattern and characteristic feed-back loops.


Hence I
recommend to address the OP’s question to a forum on neuroscience,
not to a philosophical forum.

I agree with most of what you say, except that I wouldn't call Freud's investigations "early". The Code of Ur-Nammu may be called early, perhaps still the Old Testament... ;-)

Re. "it should be possible for science ... to study when, where, and how this moral ontology exerts its influence on physical reality."
I would suggest game theory plays a role here.  In the simple game of trust
https://www.clearerthinking.org/post/evolution-of-trust-game
depending on conditions of, for example, effectiveness of communication, various mutual behaviours such as 'copycat', 'cheat' or 'always cooperate' prove to be evolutionarily successful.  So different golden rules apply depending on conditions.

I'd like to expand causative's good answer "the chairs are not ontologically privileged" by adding explicitly: Neither is morality.
My viewpoint is a decidedly materialistic one: Yes, everything, including our mental states, including our morality, is matter. The more interesting things are specifically patterns imprinted on matter, often replicating ones. "Living" beings (bacteria, humans) are prime examples for that. The stuff we are made of is famously uninteresting, at least after you burn it (before, some of the proteins etc. are interesting and precious). The interesting thing about us is how that stuff is organized. This specific, individual organization is also what constitutes our identity: After all, most of what we are made of is replaced every couple of years. Our identity is not based on what we are made of; it is based on how we are made up. The substrate (carbon chains) may not be really that important, beyond its capability to form complex patterns. It is conceivable that life develops based on a silicone chemistry, or as patterns in computers.
Morality, then, is a specific sub-pattern within the patterns that make up us humans; some might say, it is a "meme", a "mental gene". It evolves, is selected, and is reproduced.
Because morality is a specific "swirl" in the matter that makes us up there is no need to invent a step to make it have an effect in the material world (and vice versa!): It is already a part of it, as are all of our emotions and thoughts.
